# Limiting memory usage when reading files

Tags: haskell, concurrency, io, heap-memory

I'm a Haskell beginner and thought this would be good exercise. I have an
assignment where I need to read file in a thread A, handle the file lines
in threads B_i, and then output the results in thread C.

I have implemented this far already, but one of the requirements is that we
cannot trust that the entire file fits into memory. I was hoping that lazy
IO and garbage collector would do this for me, but alas the memory usage
keeps rising and rising.

The reader thread (A) reads the file with `readFile` which is then zipped
with line numbers and wrapped in Just. These zipped lines are then written
to `Control.Concurrent.Chan`. Each consumer thread B has its own channel.

Each consumer reads their own channel when it has data and if the regex
matches, it's outputted to their own respective output channel wrapped
within Maybe (made of lists).

The printer checks the output channel of each of the B threads. If none of
the results (line) is Nothing, the line is printed. Since at this point
there should be no reference to the older lines, I thought that the garbage
collector would be able to release these lines, but alas I seem to be in
the wrong here.

The .lhs file is in here:
http://gitorious.org/hajautettujen-sovellusten-muodostamistekniikat/hajautettujen-sovellusten-muodostamistekniikat/blobs/master/mgrep.lhs

So the question is, how do I limit the memory usage, or allow the garbage
collector to remove the lines.

Snippets as per requested. Hopefully indenting isn't too badly destroyed :)

```
data Global = Global {done :: MVar Bool, consumers :: Consumers}
type Done = Bool
type Linenum = Int
type Line = (Linenum, Maybe String)
type Output = MVar [Line]
type Input = Chan Line
type Consumers = MVar (M.Map ThreadId (Done, (Input, Output)))
type State a = ReaderT Global IO a


producer :: [Input] -> FilePath -> State ()
producer c p = do
  liftIO $ Main.log "Starting producer"
  d <- asks done
  f <- liftIO $ readFile p
  mapM_ (\l -> mapM_
    (liftIO . flip writeChan l) c)
    $ zip [1..] $ map Just $ lines f
  liftIO $ modifyMVar_ d (return . not)

printer :: State ()
printer = do
  liftIO $ Main.log "Starting printer"
  c <- (fmap (map (snd . snd) . M.elems)
    (asks consumers >>= liftIO . readMVar))
  uniq' c
  where head' :: Output -> IO Line
    head' ch = fmap head (readMVar ch)

    tail' = mapM_ (liftIO . flip modifyMVar_
        (return . tail))

    cont ch = tail' ch >> uniq' ch

    printMsg ch = readMVar (head ch) >>=
        liftIO . putStrLn . fromJust . snd . head

    cempty :: [Output] -> IO Bool
    cempty ch = fmap (any id)
        (mapM (fmap ((==) 0 . length) . readMVar ) ch)

    {- Return false unless none are Nothing -}
    uniq :: [Output] -> IO Bool
    uniq ch = fmap (any id . map (isNothing . snd))
        (mapM (liftIO . head') ch)

    uniq' :: [Output] -> State ()
    uniq' ch = do
      d <- consumersDone
      e <- liftIO $ cempty ch
      if not e
        then  do
          u <- liftIO $ uniq ch
          if u then cont ch else do
        liftIO $ printMsg ch
        cont ch
          else unless d $ uniq' ch
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concurrent programming offers no defined execution order unless you enforce one yourself with mvars and the like. So its likely that the producer thread sticks all/most of the lines in the chan before any consumer reads them off and passes them on. Another architecture that should fit the requirements is just have thread A call the lazy readfile and stick the result in an mvar. Then each consumer thread takes the mvar, reads a line, then replaces the mvar before proceeding to handle the line. Even then, if the output thread can't keep up, then the number of matching lines stored on the chan there can build up arbitrarily.

What you have is a push architecture. To really make it work in constant space, think in terms of demand driven. Find a mechanism such that the output thread signals to the processing threads that they should do something, and such that the processing threads signal to the reader thread that they should do something.

Another way to do this is to have chans of limited size instead -- so the reader thread blocks when the processor threads haven't caught up, and so the processor threads block when the output thread hasn't caught up.

As a whole, the problem in fact reminds me of Tim Bray's widefinder benchmark, although the requirements are somewhat different. In any case, it led to a widespread discussion on the best way to implement multicore grep. The big punchline was that the problem is IO bound, and you want multiple reader threads over mmapped files.

See here for more than you'll ever want to know: http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2007/09/20/Wide-Finder

Comment: BoundedChan is on hackage for exactly this type of use.

Comment: Thanks Tom and sciv. I'll try implementing it and mark as an answer if it works